# Installed django version conflicts with requirement loop

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to setup reviewboard in Windows using via setup.py develop

But I keep on getting: error: Installed distribution Django 1.3.1 conflicts with requirement Django==1.3.3

The weird thing is before this, I had 1.3.3 installed, then I got an error saying the requirement is 1.4.10. So I installed 1.4.10 and I got the same error saying that the requirement is 1.3.3.

I have uninstalled and installed different versions of django and I'm stuck in a loop. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: how did you install 1.4.10?

Comment: I installed it using pip

Comment: how, as in  what exact command did you use?

Comment: pip install Django==1.4.10

Comment: where did you get the package source from?